# I release all memory that I can, but my program need more, what can I do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management

This is a philosophical question. My program send message that need more memory. I release all memory I can to it continue working correct. But, the program tell that need more memory again, and I have no one to release. What I do now?

This almost happens when I am using the camera with the ZBar library, so I don't have control with the ZBar (I can't release it's memory, only mine). And this really need a lot of memory to work. Because this, I don't know what I do.

The program didn't crash, but can run unstable.

Comment: What sort of application are you writing. The next logical step would be to start optimizing memory. Start using C arrays instead of NSArrays and use structures instead of objects. If you absolutely need to, you can cache to disk/flash memory.

Comment: I update it. Was not good thing don't show when this almost happens.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ZBar, but maybe there a different library you could use to accomplish the same task, that uses less memory than ZBar.

Answer (score 6):

Without more details to your problem, your answers are going to be vague :)

The obvious answer is to use less memory.

If depends on what you're using the memory for but you could consider putting it into a file on disk and only reading in the data that you need?

You should also check for leaks - you might be using memory without realising it.

If you post more information about your exact problem, we could probably help more.

Comment: Lol, sory. I edit and show more. The problem is this happens when I using the camera with a library, not with file. Because this, I thought have no more memory to release.

Comment: OK, so a file can't help you much. Assuming you mean you're using a `ZBarReaderViewController` then when you call dismissModalViewController it should free all it's memory?

Comment: Well, I need memory to run the ViewController. Even if I dismiss the view and free memory, it don't solve my problem. But you give-me a good idea, I can dismiss the view and say to user: "memory problem, close other program". It's more politic, and he can try again.